# Navigation Controller en iOS desde código

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy haciendo un login de usuarios desde Firebase. El botón Regístrate me envía a la Vista de Registrar, contiene la un Navigation Bar para regresar, esto funciona OK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el botón Iniciar Sesión, si el usuario y contraseña son incorrectas me lanza una alerta de error (cosa que está bien), cuando es correcta se dirige a la Vista de color naranja que le he puesto de nombre Principal. El problema es que el Navigation Bar ya no aparece, hay alguna manera de activarla con código? Y salga la opción de regresar y/o poder agregar la opción de cerrar sesión?

El código de la vista rosa es el siguiente:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginUser: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Usuario: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Contra: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func IniciarSesion(sender: AnyObject) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(Usuario.text!, password: Contra.text!, completion: {
            user, error in
            if error != nil{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:"Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
            }else{
                let nuestroStoryBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let mainPrincipal = nuestroStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Princ") as! Principal
                self.presentViewController(mainPrincipal, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Cabe indicar que el botón Registrar que me dirige a la Vista Mostaza la hice con un Segue, supongo que por eso si me aparece el Navigation Bar, más no en la Naranja que lo he hecho con código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifica estas la línea;

```
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
```

por

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(alert, animated: true)
```

y después la línea;

```
self.presentViewController(mainPrincipal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

por

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainPrincipal, animated: true)
```